# How to convert a list of string to a list of a class in C#?

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of `string` like this :

```
public List<string> Subs { get; set; }
```

and I have a `list<Category> Cat { get; set; }` of this class :

```
public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int SubCat_ID { get; set; }
    }
```

I just need to put all of the values in the `list<string> Subs` into the `List<Category> Cat`. and of course each string in the `list<string>` should be placed in each *Name*  parameter of `List<Category>`.

So how is it done ? 
Is there any convert method which does the thing? how does it work ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with LINQ:

```
var cats = (from sub in Subs
            select new Category
            {
                Name = sub
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Or, in method call syntax, `subs.Select(sub => new Category { Name = sub }).ToList()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ConvertAll` method of the `List` class:

```
Cat = Subs.ConvertAll(s => new Category { Name = s });
```

Answer (score 2):

In case both lists exist, Zip should be used:

```
 var result = categories.Zip(subs, (cate, sub) =>
            {
                cate.Name = sub;
                return cate;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Select" enumerable extension method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx

followed by a "ToList()" like this:

```
var newList = Subs.Select(name => new Category { Name = name}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a function manually, otherwise it would be very hard for the program to understand what property should correspond to the string in the list.